# 404 on subfolders instead of redirect

Tags: php, apache, redirect

Sorry if asked before, i tried googling it, but without succes.

Anyway, i use some devices that send a POST to a website, which does something with it and returns something. However, when i set the device to go to www.url.com/notexistingfolder, it redirects to the https site and gives a 302 to the device, which it can not handle. 
Problem is, all other traffic(users going to the website) must be redirected to that HTTPS site.

How can i set it so that all posts that are not going to the root get a 404?
The devices can't handle HTTPS, so unfortunatly, using errorDocument 404 /var/www/url/somefile.php doesn't work.

Part of my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin server-admin@url.nl
    ServerName url.eu
    ServerAlias url.eu *.url.eu
    ErrorDocument 404 https://url.eu/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/url/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/url/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
            RewriteRule ^$ - [L]

            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soap/? [NC]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wiki/? [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    </Directory>

Alias /wiki/ "/var/www/wiki/"
    <Directory /var/www/wiki/>
            #php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
            AllowOverride All

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
            RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    </Directory>
```

Comment: `The devices can't handle HTTPS` :: improve the devices

Comment: If you think you've found the answer please delete the question.

Comment: Yeah, but the device improvement is not up to me. They are working on that, but apparently it's something that is not done in a couple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Marco's edit to his own question.

> EDIT: Never mind, I think I found a solution to give a 404 for anything going to a path:
>
> ```
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/*
>   RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
> ```

Comment: Marco, you can mark this as correct to resolve this question.

Comment: Will aprove my own answer as soon as i got it tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/*
  RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Might work, will be tested after the weekend due to vacation and the testserver not being ready yet.